# how to update scons .98 syntax for deprecated Options class to current 4.0

Tags: scons

I'm trying to build from an old scons file that uses an old Options class:

```
opts = Options()
opts.Add(BoolOption('RELEASE', 'do a release build.', 'no'))
opts.Add(BoolOption('XMINGW', 'Cross compile to win32', 'no'))
opts.Add(BoolOption('PROFILE', 'build profiling binary', 'no'))
opts.Add('DEFINES', 'things to define',0)
opts.Update(env)
```

From what I could find, it looks like this existed awhile ago per https://scons.org/doc/0.98.1/HTML/scons-user/x1640.html.

I believe the following is now the API for adding options:
https://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-user/ch10.html#sect-command-line-options

that said, I was wondering how to update the snippet above to be used for scons 4.0.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option was renamed Variable some time back.

See:
https://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-user/ch10s02.html

This change started in 0.98.1 and after (far too long as deprecated) was [removed in SCons 3.0.1](https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L608)

See https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L2637 for the initial introduction of Variables